# Create 3D model from selfie in iOS like in Lenskart?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, face-detection

How can we create 3D model from selfie like it does in LENSKART ios app?
I am trying to create 3D model from selfie and place objects in the model just like TRY IT ON feature in LENSKART.

I tried LENSKART and it seems they have integrated DITTO.
https://www.ditto.com/

Also I checked Face DJ Build app.
https://techcrunch.com/video/face-dj-builds-instant-3d-models-from-a-selfie/

I tried checking FaceTracking sample app from Apple, but it seems to support in iphone X only.

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: I haven't found anything related to it yet.

Comment: https://github.com/heinrisch/faceid-to-stl